# How can I get the exact size of incoming packet for a TCP server in C++?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to write a simple TCP server in C++ using sockets. I wanted to create a function that would read the incoming packet to a `std::string` with the exact size, but in order to do this, I need to know the exact size of the incoming packet:

```cpp
int Socket::Read(int sockfd, std::string& string)
{
    /* How can I get the size of the incoming packet before calling recv? */

    return 0;
}
```

How can I get the exact size of an incoming packet before receiving it and writing it into a buffer in C/C++?

Comment: I don't think you can. It's true that data is chopped into packets on the wire, but from the application's perspective, it's an undivided stream of bytes.

Comment: The way you get the size of the incoming data is to receive it. Allocate a buffer of whatever size you like, try and receive that much using the return value to know how much was actually written to the buffer, then append that data to the string. Repeat until you don't receive any more or you find the end of the string you're trying to receive because you implemented a protocol that marks it.

Comment: With the observations in the first two comments in mind, note also that for multibyte character encodings such as UTF-8, it's possible for the bytes corresponding to a *single* Unicode character to be split across two packets (or more!).

Comment: Send a small packet, say 4 bytes, that is the size of the subsequent packet of data.  Read the four bytes (mindful of endian-ness), and then use that to read the data payload packet.  *Voila!*

Comment: TCP is a byte stream which can be split into packets in arbitrary ways for transport and can even be differently split if packets got lost and data need to be resubmitted. Your application should therefore never assume a specific packet size. Any "message" style semantics need to be handled at the application layer instead of relying on the size of TCP packets. So far this question looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) where you likely try to use the wrong way Y to solve your problem X.

Comment: @Eljay Yes, that's exactly what I would do. But, I often use a struct with some extra metadata: `struct header { int type;  /* type of packet */ int seqno;  /* packet sequence number */ int options;  /* optional flags */ int paylen;  /* payload length */ };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing, whatsoever, that's called a "packet" when it comes to TCP sockets.

A TCP socket is an abstraction for a byte stream. Its inner mechanics are abstract, and it's simultaneously a source of arbitrary bytes that can arrive at any time, and a sink for bytes that can be written at any time, with the caveat that if the underlying transport determines that the write buffer is full the `write()` or `send()` will either return an indication that fewer bytes were written than specified by their third parameter, or they'll block until the peer reads from its socket and more bytes can be written to the socket.

It is a very common newbie error to assume that every `write()` or `send()` on a TCP socket on the sending side will be matched by a `read()` or `recv()` from a TCP socket on the receiving side. This is not true. The sender might `write()` 200 bytes, and the first `read()` or `recv()` will return the first 50 bytes, only, and the next call returns the remaining 150 bytes.

If a program does not diligently check the value returned by every `read()`, `recv()`, `write()`, or `send()` and explicitly handles every possible value, it's only a matter of time before that house of cards collapses into a pile of rubble.

It is true that the underlying transport layer, that shuffles the TCP socket's bytes between the sender and the receiver, handles that task in terms of discrete packets. However this is an internal implementation detail that is generally inaccessible from the TCP layer. You will need to restructre your program's logic so that it does not "need to know the exact size of the incoming packet", but rather treats the TCP socket as an emitter of a completely unstructured stream of bytes

It is true that on many socket stacks it's possible to determine the number of unread bytes on a socket, or a file descriptor, and have a guarantee that reading that many bytes won't block. But that still will not tell you anything useful, in terms of those mysterious entities called "packets". You might discover that your TCP socket has the same 200 unread bytes. And they still, in practice, arrived in two discrete packets of 50 and 150 bytes, and are sitting there, for your application to read them.

Comment: I ran afoul of [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) when attempting high speed (and small packet) communication between two machines.  Ahh, memories.